# Date Formatting is not working in momentjs?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

Following date formatting is not working in momentJs

```
 var date ="01-12-2015";//DD-MM-YYY
 console.info(moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: This code is working : http://codepen.io/jeremythille/pen/qdrJWO

Comment: No, that gives me `2015-01-12` in the console, along with the deprecation warning (using Chrome)

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell momentJS how to parse the string you are giving:

```
var date ="01-12-2015";//DD-MM-YYYY
console.info(moment(date, 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

> Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date. This is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release. Please refer to https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407 for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
var date ="01-12-2015";//DD-MM-YYY
date = date.replace(/-/g,"/")
console.info(moment(new Date(date)).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

Comment: This is wrong, twice wrong: using `moment(date)` falls back (see moment doc or my answer) precisely to `moment(new Date(date))` which is discouraged. and how come `new Date("01-12-2015")` is going to understand if 01 is month, day or year? Have you tried this? Invalid Date.

Comment: mozile firefox developer

Comment: yeah I have edited it after shiha reported an error in firefox. THe issue was firefox accepts / as delimiter and not - . Updayed the code once again to replace - with / . Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/s0ca3ne8/2/